# Converter query laravel em uma query RAW MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, laravel

Como fica esta query em formato RAW do MySQL?

```
$user = User::query()
        ->where(static function ($query) use ($indicador) {
            $query->where('indicador_id', $indicador)
                ->orWhere('level_ref', $indicador)
                ->orWhere('id', $indicador);
        })
        ->where('level_cnt', '<', $hLimit)
        ->when($id != -1, static function ($query) use ($id) {
            $query->where('id', '!=', $id);
        })
        ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
        ->first();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use o método `toSql()`:
https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_toSql

É um método do *Query Builder*, pode usar assim:

```
$user.ToSql();
```